# Umbraco : Multi-node tree picker xpath expression

Tags: xpath, umbraco, umbraco6

My content node looks like,

```
*  ProductList
   *  Product Category 1
      *  Product 1
         *  Fruits
            *  Fruit 1
         *  Colors
            *  red
            *  blue
       *  Product 2
          *  Fruits
             *  Fruit 2
          *  Colors
             *  green
             *  orange
```

In "Fruit 1" content, i need a multi-node tree picker, such that there appears only children of corresponding "colors" node(ie, multi-node tree picker with red and blue). Similarly, multi-node tree picker in "Fruit 2" should display only "green" and "blue". How can i make it work?

I guess it can be done by choosing "XPath Expression", if so what would be the expression to make it work?

please help, thanks

Comment: Is your input really text only without any XML/XHTML tags? In this case it will be rather difficult to use XPath since you will only be able to use the string functions, if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using the following datatype "Test" in "fruit 1" ,"fruit 2" etc

[image]